# Add-on/extension to produce quality VB code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Currently, *Smart Indent* in VS 2010 is giving me lots of headaches. Everytime I try to put each parameter of a `Sub` or a `Function` into one line like

```
Private Function Foo (ByVal a As String, _
                      ByVal i As Integer)
```

I get things like

```
Private Function Foo (ByVal a As String, _
  ByVal i As Integer)
```

Can you point me to some extension/add-on/configuration to pretty print VB code?

Comment: Why is the latter formatting not acceptable to you?

Comment: Because every function is taking it's own parameter identation (some aligned with inner statements, others one space left, etc.), making code very hard to read.

Comment: Consider this: What happens if you need to rename the function at a later time? Will you have to change the parameter indentation as well?

Comment: @Bernard I think that might be his point. If the IDE could auto format it like that he wouldn't need to worry about maintaining the formatting.

Comment: Obviously not, but I'm getting different results in each function/sub, so my problem is not exactly the format I'm getting, is that it seems that VS puts random identation.

Comment: No repro.  Have you tried Edit + Advanced + Format Document?

Comment: I have smart indenting turned on and all of my code is formatted like your first example. You should be able to format your code this way without any add-on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
Private Function Foo( _
  ByVal a As String, _ 
  ByVal i As Integer)
```

Breaking the line before the first parameter puts each of your parameters on a seperate line and treats them all identically rather than making an exception (not a pun) of the first one.